# jQuery function not working: selecting different elements in same class

Tags: jquery

The problem with the following is that the drop down menu appends to the top button div even if the bottom one is clicked.  https://jsfiddle.net/dy0m1frs/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function createDropdown() {
    var drop = $('.customDropdown');
    var i;
    var htmlString = '<div id="dropContainer">';

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) {
      htmlString += '<div class="dropOption">option ' + i + '</div>';
    }

    htmlString += '</div>';
    drop.append(htmlString);
  }

  createDropdown();



  $('.customDropdown').on('click', function(event) {
    var container = $('#dropContainer');
    var target = $(event.target);

    if (target.hasClass('valueHolder') || target.hasClass('customDropdown')) {
      container.show();
    } else if (target.hasClass('dropOption')) {
      drop.find('span.valueHolder').text(target.text());
      container.hide();
    }



  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #4E4E4E;
}
.customDropdown {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
#dropContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -1px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 192px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.btn {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#e9e9e9');
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  text-indent: -4.066px;
  border: 2px solid #dcdcdc;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 17px;
  line-height: 17px;
  width: 106px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 6px #ffffff;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e9e9e9), color-stop(1, #f9f9f9));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e9e9e9', endColorstr='#f9f9f9');
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.btn:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="customDropdown">
    <span class="valueHolder btn">Select</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="customDropdown">
    <span class="valueHolder btn">Select</span>
  </div>

</body>
```

Although new to jQuery, I thought the problem is that the `createDropdown`function is being called before the click event and that by default the first item in the class = "customDropdown" will always be used.  So I tried to redefine the variable `drop` in variable ways and call the function inside the click event but to no avail.  Any help?

For example I tried:

```
 $('.customDropdown').on('click', function(event){

        var drop = $('.customDropdown').prev();
        createDropdown();
        var container = $('#dropContainer');
        var target = $(event.target);
```

This is just a demo so I get it working; potentially I could have limitless buttons of the same class which need to display the same menu; bearing this in mind, do I need to really add another attribute to the div class?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cr7g5oxh/

Comment: cheers; what change did you make?

Comment: Oh i see; thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a number of problems. First, you're adding a div with the same id to each button. Change it to a class:

```
var htmlString = '<div class="dropContainer">';
```

Then, in your click handler, you need to find the specific div attached to the button that you clicked:

```
var container = $(this).find('.dropContainer');
```

Then, in the else if condition, the drop variable is not available as it was defined in the other function. You need to find the correct span instead:

```
$(this).find('span.valueHolder').text(target.text());
```

Finally, in your css, change the #dropContainer declaration to .dropContainer.

You'll still have some css work to do because the second button always shows over the options for the first button.

https://jsfiddle.net/dy0m1frs/5/

Comment: thanks a lot; yeah I know the button is getting in the way of the list atm